# How to add a button matrix to an asp .net page using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008

Do you have any suggestions on how to add a whole matrix of same-sized buttons (50 columns*10rows) to a page in ASPX? The page could even be filled with buttons automatically when it loads.
My first idea is to use a double FOR:

```
FOR(i=1; i<=10;i++)
{
FOR(j=1; j<=50;++)
{
Create button;
Add button to panel; (to the right of the previous button)
Set button caption to ij; 
}
Go to the next row of buttons.
}
```

How can I go to the next row? What is the coding for this, especially for placing the button? My first idea is to create a paragraph, but not sure how to do it in C#. IN ASPX I know it's a matter of inserting a `<p>.`
Is there a better alternative than this scenario? Thank you!

Comment: With a paragraph per button you won't get a matrix. A very **raw** solution may be to use a table. Even if a page with 500 buttons...will be pretty heavy. Do you really need that?

Comment: Thanks, Adriano. Actually it's a paragraph after each line, to get that matrix. But not sure how to insert it in C#. I need it for a theatre seating allocation, that's why 500 places.

Comment: You do not really need a _true_ button. If you can't use HTML5 (with Canvas) and Flash/Silverlight aren't options then you may consider to use (for example) an image map. Pick an image of the theater map. Create the image map (once and not from code) et voila.

Comment: For an example (but web is full of them, just search) take a look here: http://www.image-maps.com/united_states.php (from home page you can build your own image map on-line).

Comment: Agree with the above - 500 buttons is a fairly inefficient way to go about it. To add to it you could always use jQuery (see http://techbrij.com/784/online-ticket-booking-system-asp-net-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a row and then add a System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.GenericControl("br") to start a new row